# Potential problems when using ProfileOptimization across versions

Tags: .net, optimization, compilation, .net-4.5, jit

In a bid to improve the launch performance of my program on startup I call:

```
ProfileOptimization.SetProfileRoot(path);
ProfileOptimization.StartProfile("profile");
```

I have some questions:

Can I use the same ProfileOptimization profile across versions of my program? What happens if methods have been changed or removed?

What happens if I use one profile but run my program multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PerfView documentation states following:

> **Background JIT has the following characteristics**
>
> 1. It does not work on the VERY FIRST launch on a given machine.   There is no profile and thus nothing to act as the 'oracle' that indicates what to compile.
> 2. It does not work well if what happened on previous launches is a good indication of what will happen this time.  **For example if a particular program is typically called with command line arguments that make it do very different things on each launch, then background JIT will not work well for the startup case.**
> 3. It DOES self recover, however.   For example if the program often gets used with one set of command line argument but occasionally get used with another that will cause it to run very different code paths, then it will work well for most launches (but not the unusual command, and the one after it).
> 4. **You CAN fix the issue described above by introducing more profiles for the same application.   If you have a Profile not at START but at the start of each COMMAND then the runtime will keep a profile for each command and each of those will work well.**
> 5. Background JIT compilation tends to only be able push about 1/2 the JIT time of the scenario to the background where it does not impact end-to-end time.  This is because often the 'main thread' can 'catch up' to the background thread and need a method before the background thread could finish compiling it.  In a typical case where CPU cost associated with JIT compilation is much larger than execution of the JITTed code, this tends to result in half the methods being compiled by the main thread and half compiled by the background thread.   This is what NGENing is better than background JIT compilation.
>
> **What can go wrong with background JIT compilation.**
>
> It your program has used SetProfileRoot and StartProfile, but JIT compilation (as shown in the JITStats view) does not show any or very little background JIT compilation, there are several issues that may be responsible.   **Fundamentally a important design goal was to insure that background JIT compilation did not change the behavior of the program under any circumstances.**    Unfortunately, it means that the algorithm tends to bail out quickly.   In particular
>
> 1. When modules are loaded, a module constructor could be called, which could have side effects (even this is very rare).   Thus if background JITTing would cause a module to be loaded earlier than it otherwise would be, it could expose (rare) bugs.  Because background JIT had a very high compatibility bar, it protects against this by taging each method with the EXACT modules that were loaded at the time of JIT compilation, and only allows them to be background JIT compiled after all those EXACT modules were also loaded in the current run.   Thus if you have a scenario (say a menu opening), where sometimes more or fewer modules are loaded (because previous user actions caused different modules to load), then background JIT may not work well.
> 2. If you have attached a callback to the System.Assembly.ModuleResolve event, it is possible (although extremely unlikely and very bad design) that background JITing could have side effects if the ModuleResolve callback returned different answers on the second run than it did on the first run.   Because of this background JIT compilation is suspended the first time an ModuleResolve callback in invoked.
> 3. Because any module lookup that fails, WILL call the ModuleResolve event before it finally fails, this means that any probing for modules which fail will also inhibit background JIT compilation.

Hope it helps.